# Material UI Switch onChange handlers are not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have implemented two material ui switches that are supposed to update properties in the state, however it seems their onChange handlers are not working because the properties are not getting updated(however I am able to flip the switches' controls). The expected behaviour would be when I flip on / off the switch and click save, the properties in the state would change. For reference to the switch api, visit this link - https://material-ui.com/components/switches/#Switches.js

Here is what i have implemented.

```
export class SwitchNotifications extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email_notification_enabled: false,
      app_notification_enabled: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    let detail = details(token);
    this.props.dispatch(fetchProfile(detail.username));
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      email_notification_enabled: nextProps.profile.email_notification_enabled,
      app_notification_enabled: nextProps.profile.app_notification_enabled
    });
  }

  handleChangeEmailNotification  = event => {
    this.setState({ email_notification_enabled: event.target.checked });
  };
  handleChangeAppNotification  = event => {
    this.setState({ app_notification_enabled: event.target.checked });
  };



  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const new_profile = {
      email_notification_enabled: this.state.email_notification_enabled,
      app_notification_enabled: this.state.app_notification_enabled
    };
    let data = { profile: new_profile };
    this.props.dispatch(updateProfileAction(this.state.username, data));
  };

  render() {
    const {

      app_notification_enabled,
      email_notification_enabled
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <div className="containers">
          <div className="upload-profile-form edit-upload-course-form">
            <img id="member-img" src={image} />
            <br />

            <Grid container spacing={3}>

              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={
                    <Switch
                      checked={app_notification_enabled}
                      onChange={this.handleChangeAppNotification}
                      value={app_notification_enabled}
                      inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
                    />
                  }
                  label="App notifications"
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={
                    <Switch
                      checked={email_notification_enabled}
                      onChange={this.handleChangeEmailNotification}                      
                      value={email_notification_enabled}
                      color="primary"
                      inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
                    />
                  }
                  label="Email notifications"
                />
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <button
                  onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                  className="submit-profile-button"
                >
                  {" "}
                  SAVE
                </button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the `handleSubmit` logic. What you have [seems to work](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-90ltu), but you aren't showing how you try to verify the result.

Comment: Thanks @RyanCogswell, I have updated the code to include handleSubmit.

Comment: So what is it that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I am not sure but I feel like the problem is around the way  i have implemented the material ui switch components

Comment: No, I mean specifically what doesn't work -- what results are you looking at that are incorrect and how are you looking at them?

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem was actually in my Django backend. I was not capturing the values well.